# Get multiple values from input type file javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to ask how to get and display the titles of the files from the input type file when multiple is enabled using javascript.

```
<input id="myInput" type="file" multiple/>
<label id="inpFiles"></label>
```

I tried using document.getElementById("myInput").value but it only returns the first file.

Comment: you need to use for loop for getting multiple files name.
var files = document.getElementById("myInput").files
for(var i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
 console.log(files[i].name+'----'+files[i].size);
}

Answer (score 1):

The below binds to the `change` event, then prints the name of each file attached to the input to the console.

```js
$('#myInput').on('change', function(e) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.target.files, function(file) {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" type="file" multiple/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access its file array
Example:

`document.getElementById("myInput").files[0].name`
`document.getElementById("myInput").files[1].name`

Comment: This greatly helped me without using loops.Cheers!

Comment: @harveycarope please accept my post as answer if it helped